# How to recompose my codes on PhpStorm

Tags: php, phpstorm

Is there any way to beautify and understandable my php code on PhpStorm.
I have tried Reformat code but not working.

For example; When I write below line

```
$example = array("key_one" => "value one", "key_two" => "value two", "key_three" => "value three");
```

Is there any shortcut or settings on menu.
My code should be recompose below.

```
$example = array(
    "key_one"   => "value one", 
    "key_two"   => "value two", 
    "key_three" => "value three"
);
```

I hope i have made a sufficient explanation.

Thank you.

Comment: May the documentation helps: http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/webhelp/reformatting-source-code.html

Comment: *"I have tried Reformat code but not working."* Please try again -- you have not tried hard enough. (HINT: setting up formatting rules before reformatting may help: `Settings | Code Style | PHP`)

Comment: **Google** is your friend.

Comment: `alt+ctrl+l`, but im not sure if this is just the company standard or phpStorm standard. Google will help

Comment: I reviewed google and other settings but reformatcode not working like I want.
All codes recompose beautify but arrays not like I want.

Answer (score 0):

It is `Alt + Ctrl + L`. Look at the default keymap, found under Help->Default Keymap Reference

[image]

Comment: First thanx your answer. But reformatcode not working. I guess i should a settings for reformat code.

Comment: Look into `File->Settings->Code Style->PHP`. Click on the tab named "other". There you see how the code is formatted. If there's no array in it, place an array in there with the formatting you want.